# How to convert JSONB[] to JSONB?

Tags: postgresql

I have this table with existing data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table (
    col JSONB[],
);
```

How can I convert `col` to `JSONB` now without dropping the column?

I tried:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table
ALTER COLUMN col TYPE JSONB USING col::jsonb
```

But it says `cannot cast type jsonb[] to jsonb`

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick:

```sql
ALTER TABLE table
ALTER COLUMN blocks col JSONB USING to_json(col)
```